# negative eigenvalue for elliptic operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the elliptic (the matrix $a^{ij}$ is positive definite) operator with smooth coefficients
\begin{equation}
    Lu = -\sum \partial_{x_j} (a^{ij}(x) \partial_{x_i}u ) + c(x) u
\end{equation}

in the bounded domain $U$ with smooth boundary $\partial U$. Asuming the Neumann condition, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = 0$ on $\partial U$, show that $L$ must have a negative eigenvalue if
\begin{equation}
    \int_U c(x) dx \leq 0 \text{ and } c(x) \neq 0
\end{equation}

for some $x \in U$.

To solve this I was thinking of writing $L$ in nondivergence form and writing the bilinear form $B[u, v] = \int_U \sum a^{ij} u_{x_i} v_{x_j} + \sum b^i u_{x_i} v + (c-\lambda)uv dx$ (where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $u$) and showing that $|B[u, v] \leq \alpha |u||v|$ and $\beta |u|^2 \leq B[u, u]$ to verify the conditions fo the Lax-Milgram theorem. But I'm not sure how to do that and I think there should be an easier way.

Comment: I think it’s easier than that. Try not to do anything too sophisticated.

Comment: I agree, though I can't put my finger on what the easier way should be

Comment: Do you know what is the variational characterization of the eigenvalues? It's covered in Evans (at least for the Dirichlet boundary case).

Comment: I think I know what you're referring to. This is is Theorem 2 of chapter 6. However, this tells us the principle eigenvalue is positive (not negative)

Comment: In Evan they assumed $c=0$, which is a bit different from your situation.

Comment: That's true, how woul di modify what they did to deal with my case?